# Date transformation JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, iso8601

I'm using [this Vue component](https://github.com/mariomka/vue-datetime) on my frontend that allows my user to pick a date and time. As it is, this provides the date/time in ISO 8601 format. I was then doing this to transform for the database:

```
$dt = $request->pickup_date_time;
$formattedDt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dt));
```

However, I'm finding that when there's a timezone difference between the client and the server, the transformed date is off.

As an example, a user in Texas might pick 10am as the time but when it processes on the server, it's being transformed to 4pm (6 hour time difference between Texas and London).

What's the best way to transform so that we always store the users selected time?

Comment: It's pretty broad and opinionated as there are many different solutions out there.  Some use unix timestamps, some use ISO formats with only UTC and some accept timezone offsets and convert it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you post pick_date_time as a UNIX timestamp and save that, you won't need to do any string parsing at the php level. Then you can use that timestamp in JS to render in the browser's timezone.

Comment: yeah, I can't change the format of what is posted from the front end

Answer (score 0):

You need to find timezone differance between server and user. For doing that you need to use javascript & jquery.

We're going to get timezone offset with jquery and store it in session. Before inserting user's date to database we're going to add this offset.

Check [getTimezoneOffset (javascript)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

> Step 1: If timezone offset is posted, store it in user_timezone isset.
>
> Step 2: If there is no user_timezone isset, get it.
>
> Step 3: Add this offset to date which is picked by user. Then insert it to database.

Lets create a new php file. And include it before letting user pick date.

```
    <?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }
        //If timezone_offset is posted, save it as user_timezone
         if (isset($_POST['timezone_offset'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_timezone'] = $_POST['timezone_offset'];
        }
        //If user_timezone is not exist, get it.
        else if (!isset($_SESSION['user_timezone'])) {
    ?>
        //Include jQuery
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var url = location.href;
                var timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
                    var posting = $.post( url, { timezone_offset: timezone_offset } );
                    posting.done(function() {
                        location.reload();
                    });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

We get the offset. Now let's add this offset to date.

```
$dt = $request->pickup_date_time;
$Fdate = strtotime($dt) + (60 * $_SESSION['user_timezone']);
```

Now, you can insert $Fdate to your database.

For displaying this date in local timezone:

```
$Fdate = $Fdate - (60 * $_SESSION['user_timezone']);
$formattedDt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $Fdate);
```

Excuse my English, English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

The actual ISO8601 spec includes the timezone. If it's not specified in the string the receiving server is going to make an assumption that's probably not correct. So the solution is to include the timezone in the date string.

```
$preferred_timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');
$t = new DateTime('now', $preferred_timezone);

var_dump(
    $t->format('c'),
    $t->format(DateTime::ISO8601),
    $t->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP')
);
```

Output:

```
string(25) "2019-01-21T16:39:08-08:00"
string(24) "2019-01-21T16:39:08-0800"
string(25) "2019-01-21 16:39:08-08:00"
```

If the receiving side can't properly handle a timezone and is only *pretending* to be ISO8601-*ish* then you need to configure your application with knowledge of what the remote server is expecting and translate accordingly.

```
$preferred_timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');
$remote_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris');

$t = new DateTime('now', $preferred_timezone);
$t->setTimeZone($remote_timezone);

var_dump(
    $t->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

Output:

```
string(19) "2019-01-22 01:42:54"
```